# React js es6 validation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, reactive-programming

Am new to react js and am using es6 js version of coding and material ui . Here,my code seems like

```
class Components extends React.Component {


render() {

    return ( < div style = {
            styles.root
        } >
        <
        GridList cols = {
            2
        }
        padding = {
            1
        }
        cellHeight = {
            40
        }
        style = {
            styles.gridList
        } >
        <
        GridTile cols = {
            1
        }
        rows = {
            2
        } > < TextField type = "email"
        floatingLabelText = "Email Id"
        onChange = {
            this.changeValue.bind(this, 'Email')
        }
        /></GridTile >
        <
        GridTile cols = {
            1
        }
        rows = {
            2
        } > < TextField floatingLabelText = "Record Name"
        onChange = {
            this.changeValue.bind(this, 'recordname')
        }
        /></GridTile >
        <
        GridTile > < DatePicker hintText = "Start Date"
        ref = "startdate"
        mode = "landscape"
        onChange = {
            this.changeValue.bind(this, 'strtdate')
        }
        /></GridTile >
        <
        GridTile > < DatePicker hintText = "End Date"

        mode = "landscape"
        onChange = {
            this.changeValue.bind(this, 'enddate')
        }
        /></GridTile >
        <
        GridTile cols = {
            1
        }
        rows = {
            3
        } > < TextField floatingLabelText = "Sheet Type"
        onChange = {
            this.changeValue.bind(this, 'sheetname')
        }
        /></GridTile >
        <
        GridTile cols = {
            1
        }
        rows = {
            3
        } > < /GridTile> < /
        GridList > <
        /div>
    );
}}
```

Having multiple input boxes like this, i need to do require and email validation. I saw some examples using `React.PropTypes.number` in es5 type. I cant get any idea to do this.

Comment: Hi ! Can you indent your code please ?

Comment: Hi @F.Kauder, edited the code and just take a look at **TextField**  those are the input fields which need to validate required/email so and so.

Comment: This is not indented. Here's a guide to know how must be organize and indent your code (https://web-design-weekly.com/2015/01/29/opinionated-guide-react-js-best-practices-conventions/) and here's a true example of React code (https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/components/App/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

For validations, an Input component can be created which will accept the pattern as the prop. After the validation gets fired, the value gets updated in the parent component, Form. An example in React is available in my public repo - nyanam. I am highlighting only the relevant components for illustration.

1. [Input component](https://github.com/vijayst/nyanam/blob/master/imports/ui/components/form/input.jsx)
2. [Form component](https://github.com/vijayst/nyanam/blob/master/imports/ui/components/form/form.jsx)